# Find the max length of continuous white space in an array

Tags: c++

There is a array filled with char elements, can you suggest a most efficient way to find the max length of continuous white space?

Comment: What do you define whitespace as? Just spaces, or newlines, etc. as well?

Comment: What did you answer? Was it `O(n)`?

Comment: Do tabs work as one space?  Or a hard tab?  Or a soft tab?  What about newlines?

Comment: space, hard tab, tab, newline - who cares? it's a question about algorithm..

Comment: @Andrew Marshall; @templatetypedef: White space is well defined.

Comment: I can't think of way quicker than O(n) but then again the obvious bruit force solution is also O(n). So in contemplation: Stupid question that obviously has not been though thorough.

Comment: yes, white space is just spaces, and I gave a O(n) algorithm, but the interviewer said " improve it ".

Comment: There's no way that this can be done faster than `O(n)` because you must check every element to see if it is whitespace. Even with certain optimizations to make it a faster `O(n)`, it still is indeed `O(n)`.

Comment: The worst case is O(n) obviously. The _average_ case may not be, depending on input.

Answer (score 15):

Scan the array from left to right, keep a count of white space. When you reach a non-whitespace character, check that count against the current max; if it's higher, it becomes the new max.  Skip forwards this max number in the array - if it is not whitespace you know the interval cannot contain the max whitespace.  Otherwise search backwards to where whitespace started - find that set your count and continue from where you had previously skipped to.

I believe worst case performance of this would be O(n) and best case would be O(sqrt(n)) for the case where there is a sqrt(n) start of whitespace followed by non-whitespace on every skip point (causing repeated skipping to the end of the array).

Comment: hey, yes, I've thought the way during the interview, but I think the worst situation of this algorithm is also O(n). And would you pls give me the average cost of this algorithm? better to attach the process of analysis.

Comment: I've edited in what I think to be the best and worst case, but actual performance would depend on the data.  Single spaced documents would only perform at O(n) but documents with good chunks of whitespace and text would perform very well.  Consecutive spaces at the start of the array favour this algorithm (as it gets the max used to skip up early).

Comment: +1 -- good answer. You're doing basically a Boyer-Moore-Horspool type search, except that you're essentially synthesizing the string(s) you search for on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

scan the array left to right, keep a count of white space.  When you reach a non-whitespace character, check that count against the current max; if it's higher, it becomes the new max.  Set the count back to zero, continue scanning.  This is O(n) and you can't really do better because you have to touch each element at least once.

Comment: yes, if we should traverse the whole array, the O(n) is the best. But if we use some special operate as & or |...... I don't know, may there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to scan whole array. Just keep checking remaining data also if it is less than current max white spaces, then stop the scanning.

example

1 space space 2 space space scape 3 4

here after coming to 3 u know that only 2 elements are left and those are less than ur current max spaces (3).

Answer (score 0):

A char array is nothing but a string. so basically you are trying to find max length of continuous space. Assuming your char array is single dimensional i.e. single string and not array of strings.

```c
int maxSpaceLength = 0;
int currentSpaceCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    if (charArray[i] == ' ') {
        currentSpaceCount++;
    } else {
        if(maxSpaceLength < currentSpaceCount)
            maxSpaceLength = currentSpaceCount;
        currentSpaceCount = 0;
    }
}

return maxSpaceLength;
```